# "Can't find/load security.manager" java -Djava.security.manager MyApp

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cmd, rmi, securitymanager

According to my book i have to start my application with following cmd:

`java -Djava.security.manager MyApp`

But my command prompt tells me that he can't find/load mainclass security.manager.
I also don't understand why i have to start my application outside of Intellij.

Comment: If it thinks you're trying the run main class `security.manager`, then you seem to have a space after `-Djava.`, possibly an invisible space. Try *typing* the command again. Don't copy/paste it. --- You don't have to run outside Intellij. You can specify the `-D` option when running inside Intellij. I don't use Intellij, so can't tell you exactly where, but in Eclipse it's the VM options input in the Run Configuration object used to run the Java code.

Comment: Thanks. I was using PowerShell instead of command prompt. Now it works. -Djava was colored in grey and security.manager was colored in white.